# Simulate Key Press - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to simulate or trigger keyboard press. I don't want to capture but to simulate it. Example:

Pseudocode:

simulate('a')
simulate('b')

the action was like pressing the 'a' then 'b' of the keyboard with just a piece code. No manual/actual pressing of keyboard happens.

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='text']")[0].focus();
  simulate( $(document), "a"); 
 });

 function simulate( $element, char )
 {
 var e = $.Event('keypress');
 e.which = char.charCodeAt(0);
 $element.trigger(e);
 }
</script>

After it load and focus on the input. The input must be filled with letter 'a'